# No entran los datos para la grafica Angular

Tags: html, mysql, angular, typescript, api

Estoy intentando hacer una grafica de pastel en unaaplicacion de angular, tengo el siguiente codigo:

home.component.html

```
            <div class="col-md-4">
                <lbd-chart
                  [title]="'Estadisticas de genero'"
                  [subtitle]="'Total del publico de la pagina'"
                  [chartClass]="'ct-perfect-fourth'"
                  [chartType]="emailChartType"
                  [chartData]="emailChartData"
                  [legendItems]="emailChartLegendItems"
                  [withHr]="true"
                  [footerIconClass]="''"
                  [footerText]="''">
                </lbd-chart>
            </div>
```

home.component.ts

```
    this.apiService.getEstadisticaGeneros().subscribe(
        e=>{
          this.estadisticaGeneros=e;
          var1 = this.estadisticaGeneros.find(x=>x.sexo == "0").cantidad;
          var2 = this.estadisticaGeneros.find(x=>x.sexo == "1").cantidad;
          var3 = this.estadisticaGeneros.find(x=>x.sexo == "2").cantidad;
          console.log(this.estadisticaGeneros);
          console.log(var1);

          this.emailChartData = {  <--- CUANDO LLEGA AQUI EL COMPILADOR SALTA
            labels: ["Hombre", "Mujer", "Otro"],
            series: [var1,var2,var3]
          };
          this.emailChartLegendItems = [ <--- AQUI TAMBIEN
            { title: 'Hombres', imageClass: 'fa fa-circle text-danger' },
            { title: 'Mujeres', imageClass: 'fa fa-circle text-warning' },
            { title: 'No binarios', imageClass: 'fa fa-circle text-info' }
          ];
        }
      );
```

Las variables var me devuelven el porcentaje de hombres y mujeres registrados en una base de datos, el problema es que cuando corro la aplicacion no aparece nada, ni en la consola me aparece ningun error.
Algo curioso es que lo he intentado correr paso por paso a ver que esta haciendo y cuando llega a la linea de *this.emailChartData = {* se la salta directamente, no entra a asignar los datos, lo mismo pasa cuando llega a la linea *this.emailChartLegendItems = [*
No tengo idea porque el compilador se esta salando estas lineas pero cuando voy pongo el codigo afuera del metodo con datos estaticos me aparece bien la grafica.
Tampoco es que los datos esten vacios, ya que los muestro por consola para veificar.

Comment: Se salta las líneas porque el depurador evalúa instrucción por instrucción. Y aunque veas que son varias líneas en realidad es una sola instrucción de asignación .

Comment: Entonces porque no asigna los valores? :(

Comment: Cuál biblioteca usas para las gráficas?